# Apache Camel + MongoDB documentation incorrect?

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

I'm reading the instructions on [using *findOneByQuery* using Apache Camel + MongoDB](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/mongodb-component.html#_query_operation)s, and I *think* I'm doing exactly what it says:

```
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
import deletion.manager.Constants;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbConstants;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class NotifyClientRoute extends RouteBuilder {
// ...
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

      from("direct:findOneByQuery")
        .setHeader(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA, Filters.eq("name", "Raul Kripalani"))
        .to("mongodb:myDb?database=flights&collection=tickets&operation=findOneByQuery")
        .to("mock:resultFindOneByQuery");
```

I'm getting this compilation error:

> Cannot resolve method 'setHeader(java.lang.String, org.bson.conversions.Bson)'

I've tried looking around for other/better examples, but I haven't been able to find any. The options for `setHeader` are:

```
#setHeader(String name)
#setHeader(String name, Expression expression)
#setHeader(String name, Supplier<Object>)
```

I'm pretty sure I'm importing correct classes. I'd rather not create a simple Bean class just so I can `@Autowired` a `MongoTemplate`, but that's looking like my only option right now. Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: It should be `setHeader(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA, constant(Filters.eq("name", "Raul Kripalani")))`. Are you able to create PR with the fix if that worked? The page is generated from this adoc file https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-mongodb/src/main/docs/mongodb-component.adoc

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Feel free to post it as an _actual_ answer to this question. I'll try and find the time to submit a PR for a few things in that documentation.